# Как при выборе операции очищать input?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```js
function calc() {
  var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value)
  var op = document.getElementById("opr").value

  if (op == "+") {
    n1 = "";
    document.getElementById('result').value = n1 + n2;
  }
  if (op === "-") {

    document.getElementById('result').value = n1 - n2;
  }
  if (op === "x") {
    document.getElementById('result').value = n1 * n2;
  }
  if (op === "/") {
    document.getElementById('result').value = n1 / n2;
  }
  if (op === "%") {
    document.getElementById('result').value = n1 % n2;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Calculator
</h1>
<input type="text" id="n1">
<select id="opr">
  <option value="+">+</option>
  <option value="-">-</option>
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="/">/</option>
  <option value="%">%</option>
</select>

<input type="Button" value="=" onclick="calc();">
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("opr").addEventListener('change', e => document.getElementById("n1").value = '')` вставте перед функой `calc`

Comment: можно так: `<select onchange="n1.innerHTML=''">`